# Selenium can't get past login page after switching django database from sqlite to postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, selenium, django-orm

I am attempting to switch my Django 1.9 project from sqlite to postgres. I installed postgres on my system and changed the Django settings successfully. I can write to the database and pull data from it just fine when I use my browser to manually test it. Also, all my unit tests pass.

However, my Selenium tests all fail on the login page. Every view in my project requires a login. I can manually create a new user and login without a problem. However, when my Selenium tests try to do the same thing, they can't get past the login page.

I've fiddled with this for awhile, and can't figure out exactly where the issue is coming from.

Here's the first part of my test_functional.py:

```
class SeleniumTest(TestCase, StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    """
    This class tests the task functionalities of the task manager
    """

    # Setup and teardown
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(4)

        # Create a context object that can be used later
        test_superuser = User.objects.create_superuser(
            username=test_superuser_username,
            email=test_superuser_email,
            password=test_superuser_password,
        )
        test_context = Context.objects.create(
            name=test_context_name,
            user=User.objects.get(username=test_superuser_username)
        )
        test_task = Task.objects.create(
            name=test_task_name,
            created_by=test_superuser,
            supervisor=test_superuser
        )
        test_project = Project.objects.create(
            name=test_project_name,
            created_by=test_superuser,
            supervisor=test_superuser
        )

        # Relate these to each other
        test_task.context.add(test_context)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def log_user_in(self, user_object, password):
        """
        This is designed to be a helper function that logs the user in.
        :param user_object: this is the user
        :param password: this is a string representing the password
        :return:
        """
        # Try to pull up task index, make sure you get redirected
        self.browser.get(str(self.live_server_url) + reverse('task_manager:index'))
        self.assertTrue('login' in self.browser.current_url)
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(10)
        # Login
        self.browser.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(user_object.username)
        self.browser.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password)
        self.browser.find_element_by_name('submit').click()


    def test_whether_setup_is_writing_users_to_database(self):
        """
        This test just ensures that the setUp function above
        writes to the database
        """
        test_superuser = User.objects.get(username=test_superuser_username)
        self.assertEqual(
            test_superuser.email,
            test_superuser_email,
        )
```

The test_whether_setup_is_writing_users_to_database test passes just fine.

Continuing with the SeleniumTests class in test_functional.py:

```
def test_that_user_can_create_project(self):
        """
        This test starts with an already created task and project.
        The user creates the relationship between the task and project,
        then checks the details page of each to ensure that both show
        up on the other's page
        """
        # Constants
        local_test_project_name = 'Test_Project_29k23'

        # Get user and log in
        self.user = User.objects.get(username=test_superuser_username)
        # Log user in
        self.log_user_in(user_object=self.user, password=test_superuser_password)
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(4)
        # Go to task index
        task_index_url = str(self.live_server_url) + reverse('task_manager:index')
        self.browser.get(task_index_url)
        # Quick check to make sure we're on index page
        self.assertEqual(task_index_url, self.browser.current_url)
....
```

This test fails when it asserts that the current url is anything past login page. The login just fails. Again, it doesn't do that when I test it manually, and it didn't do it with the sqlite database. I'm using the defaults in django.contrib.auth for the login view. The login template is as follows:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Try again.</p>
{% endif %}

{% if next %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed, please login with an account that has access.</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

<form method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.username }} </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>
<p><a href="{% url 'password_reset' }">Lost password?</a></p>

{% endblock %}
```

Finally, the part of my settings.py with the database settings:

```
with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'secrets.json')) as f:
    secrets = json.loads(f.read())

def get_secret(setting, secrets=secrets):
    """
    Get the secrete variable or return explicit exception. See
    2 scoops of django p. 55 for more
    """
    try:
        return secrets[setting]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = "Set the {0} environment variable".format(setting)
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': get_secret("POSTGRES_DB_NAME"),
        'USER': get_secret("POSTGRES_USER"),
        'PASSWORD': get_secret('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': get_secret('POSTGRES_HOST'),
        'PORT': get_secret('POSTGRES_PORT')
    }
```

I use a separate file, secrets.json, for the actual credentials.

I've tried to pin down where this is coming from, and I haven't been able to, so I apologize if I left out relevant information.

EDIT: [Here is the traceback](http://pastebin.com/xV4RNLiy).

EDIT 2: To try to isolate the issue, I added a test to test_functional.py that logs in using the same credentials, but using Django's test client rather than Selenium. That test passes. Here's the test:

```
def test_whether_login_works_with_django_test_client(self):
    """
    This tests whether the login works, only not using selenium
    """
    c = Client()
    login_dict = {
        'username': test_superuser_username,
        'password': test_superuser_password,
        'next':     reverse('task_manager:index')
    }
    response = c.post(path=reverse('login'), data=login_dict)
    self.assertRedirects(response=response, expected_url=reverse('task_manager:index'))
```

EDIT 3: The issue is definitely with the postgres setup, but I cannot figure out what it is. If I change the database back to sqlite (and make no other changes to the code), all tests pass. Switching back to postgres, the Selenium tests fail. However, when I manually test it with my browser using the runserver feature of manage.py, everthing works find and I can write to and read from the database.

Comment: When the Selenium test tries to log in and fails, do you examine the page content to see _why_ it failed?  Does your application perform any logging on a failed login attempt?

Comment: I can tell that the request.user.is_authenticated is false, but I don't know why. I'm pretty new, so I'm not sure how to get more insight on why exactly it's not authenticating.

Comment: Your page template displays `Your username and password didn't match. Try again` if the password is wrong.  Are you checking the result page for that text?

Comment: `test_superuser_username` and `test_superuser_password` are referenced several times in your code but I don't see where they are defined.  Can you post this code?  Are you sure they contain the correct values?

Comment: I posted the traceback on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/xV4RNLiy), which shows the page source when the test fails to the body above. It's not saying that the username and password didn't match, so for whatever reason the {% if form.errors %} conditional is not being tripped.

As to the constants, they're set at the beginning of the test_functional.py. [Here](http://pastebin.com/UYbGR4hh) is the full test_functional.py on pastebin.

Comment: @John, I think I've narrowed it down to some kind of issue with the postgres setup.  I left all my code the exact same, except in settings.py I switched the database back to sqlite. All tests passed. I switch the database back to postgres, the Selenium tests fail. Yet manual tests work fine. I'm stumped.